# Why ‘‘君のこと‘‘好きです。

Tags: grammar

I'm a beginner in Japanese. So why do they use  君のこと to mean you? If I write this same phase but instead of 君のこと I write 君は the meaning will change?

Comment: A side note, but it would be 君が好きです, not 君は好きです if you're simply trying to tell someone you like them :)